# Returning C++ const item, depending whether exists, safely

Tags: c++, stl

I have an `std::unordered_map<uint64_t, Object> _map` and I'd like to provide a read-only getter for clients.

Originally I thought of this:

```
bool foundItem(const uint64_t key, Object& object) const
{
    if(_map.find(key) != _map.end())
    {
        object = _map.at(key);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but obviously that isn't read-only, so I changed the signature to return the object and the bool can be passed by reference:

```
const Object& foundItem(const uint64_t key, bool& found) const
{
    if(_map.find(key) != _map.end())
    {
        found = true;
        return _map.at(key);
    }
    else
    {
        found = false;
        // What can I return here??
    }
}
```

but now I have no type to return if the key is not found.

What is the best way to allow the user read-only access to the (maybe) returned object?

Comment: Maybe an `std::optional<std::ref>`, throw an exception, return a reference to a known "invalid" instance, return a pointer and `nullptr` if it's missing. It depends on how you want to user to handle it.

Comment: *"but obviously that isn't read-only"* That's not obvious to me. What is not read-only? I don't see anything being written to except `object` parameter, which is kind of the point. I don't quite grasp the nature of your objection to this approach.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I meant the client could modify the object after retrieving it because it's a ref argument, not const-ref argument

Comment: It's their object - why is it a problem if they modify it?

Comment: @Igor: It's not their object. It's owned by encapsulating class.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Owned how? I don't understand. The caller passes a place into which to store the result. The method copies the result into that spot. The caller is free to later use this space as they see fit - it's the space they own. `_map` remains unchanged throughout.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well in that case I suppose sure but I don't think the OP realised that's how references work. It seems clear they want read-only interface to data _in the map_. Ofc the real problem with that first approach is an unnecessary copy-assign

Comment: I don't follow where my misunderstanding of references arises?

Comment: @user997112 `Object& object` is a reference to some other user provided `Object`. `object = _map.at(key);` copies the value of the object from your map into the one provided by the user. But it's just a copy. No matter what the user does to the `Object` they provided, it does not impact the map in any way. So it's not clear what the concern is, regarding "read-only"ness.

Comment: Off-topic: you have a double map lookup (`find` and `at`) – `find` returns an iterator to a pair containing the value as well, so you can do: `auto i = find(); if(i != end()) { object = i->second; }`

Comment: @FançoisAndrieux I think what the OP means is that in the first function, it's impossible to force it to be read only. If it becomes `const Object&`, then the function can't fill the reference of the found object. If they leave it as is, the caller can modify the object (I think). Hence the desire to return a constant reference instead.

Comment: @Chipster you're absolutely correct

Comment: @Aconcagua I only used at() because operator[] isn't const-compatible

Comment: @user997112 That doesn't change anything – even if a compatible overload for `operator[]` *did* exist, the latter would produce a double lookup again. Only way to avoid double lookup is using the iterator returned by `find` as shown in my previous comment...

Comment: @user997112 For comparison: Inserting elements: `map[key] = value;` *always* updates the value at key. If you wanted to update only if it did not exist: `if(find() == end()) map[key] = value;` again produces the same double lookup; to be able to avoid, there are `insert` and `emplace` functions; both insert only, if the key is not yet there, and return a pair of iterator and bool, the latter indicating, if the element actually has been inserted (true) or if there was already another one (false), the former pointing to the element either newly inserted or already contained.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could return a pointer:

```
// Returns nullptr if not found
const Object* getItem(const uint64_t key) const
{
    auto it = _map.find(key);
    if (it == _map.end())
       return nullptr;

    return &it->second;
}
```

Or you could return a `std::optional`, or you could return `const Object&` but throw an exception on lookup failure.

In all cases, be careful to document the expected lifetime of the result. In particular, you should comment which member functions will result in the result of *this* function being invalidated. Usually that'll be "any non-`const` function", like how `std::string::c_str()` is valid until you do mutatey things on the string.